# What's the correct way to replace a palette in TYPO3 TCA (Table Configuration Array)?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

#### My situation

The default TCA configures two different palettes for tt_content:

- `header`
- `headers` (same as header, except the subheader field is added)

Per default, only the cType `header` uses the `headers` palette. All other default content elements (css_styled_content or fluid_styled_content) uses the `header` palette.

#### My actual alternative solution aka workaround

I know it's possible within my theme/sitepackage extension to add the subheader field to specific CEs in `ext:mytheme/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    'subheader',
    'textmedia,bullets,table,uploads,menu,shortcut',
    'after:header'
);
```

#### Better solution?

It feels not so nice only replacing `header` string with `headers` string in the appropriate showitem config.

Is there a better/correct way of replacing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the "showitem" array and use the *headers* palette like this (but i dont know if this is really better than your solution):

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['uploads'] = array_replace_recursive(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['uploads'],
    [
        'showitem' => '
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.header;headers,rowDescription,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:media;uploads,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.uploads_layout;uploadslayout,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,
        --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.extended
        ',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Boris. Completely overwriting is possible - I asked if there is a well working solution to just replace a palette, or a field. Anyway, as already talked in private chat - I think using those default content elements isn't the way to go anymore. Therefore, I will do a simple replacement for now.